# Tooltips text and background are same color in gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, tooltip

My tooltips are completely black boxes.  <strike>I can't tell if they are displaying incorrectly, or if it is just that</strike> I can see the text very faintly, so it must be that the text and background are both near-black.

I'm using gnome-shell in Ubuntu 11.10,in which settings manager doesn't have the option to change the colors in the tooltips, just background and theme settings.

Any idea what should I do?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To circumvent this sort of problem it may be useful to choose a different theme under Settings->Appearance.